# Xcode fails codesigning even though keys, certs and profiles are present and identifiers match up

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, codesign

### project config:

- `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "iPhone Developer: Maarten Billemont (9V38BLC46F)";`
- `PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "6A477BC7-051A-4FE4-B285-E6E658937C24";`

### profile:

`profile.mobileprovision.plist` is the plist contents of the mobile provisioning profile:

```
$ PlistBuddy -c 'Print :Name' profile.mobileprovision.plist
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *

$ PlistBuddy -c 'Print :UUID' profile.mobileprovision.plist
6A477BC7-051A-4FE4-B285-E6E658937C24

$ PlistBuddy -c 'Print :DeveloperCertificates' profile.mobileprovision.plist | grep -a Maarten
QTZ8SQGT6H1907U0iPhone Developer: Maarten Billemont (9V38BLC46F)10U

$ PlistBuddy -c 'Print :DeveloperCertificates:1' profile.mobileprovision.plist | openssl md5
cc0e202ff8be100352e04a4e9cc8763a

$ openssl md5 < ios_development.cer
cc0e202ff8be100352e04a4e9cc8763a

$ openssl x509 -inform der -subject -noout < ios_development.cer
subject= /UID=QTZ8SQGT6H/CN=iPhone Developer: Maarten Billemont (9V38BLC46F)/OU=7PCL8KGYD3/O=Tristan Interactive Inc./C=CA
```

### keychain:

- Common Name: iPhone Developer: Maarten Billemont (9V38BLC46F)
- This certificate is valid.
- This certificate has an associated private key.
- This certificate and its private key are in the default keychain.

### build result:

```
Check dependencies

Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *”) were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'
```

### question

What could be causing this code sign error?  What other information could I gather to diagnose the problem?  Can I somehow find out the exact `codesign` command used to double-check it's using the exact identifiers from the project configuration?  How does it determine what keychain to look at?  Can I run it in debug/diagnostic/verbose mode?

Comment: It often helps to go to preferences and refresh there, to download latest profiles & stuff from ios dev center into XCode's local cache, in addition to other suggestions.

Comment: @RobP while this "magic fix" sometimes helps, I know I have the correct and up-to-date provision profiles, keys and certificates installed as detailed by the question.  Refreshing sadly doesn't change anything.

Comment: ah well, gotta try the simplest things first. I imagine you've inspected your keychain ad nauseum by now?

Answer (score -1):

It is pretty well explained in the error message that the specified provisioning profile's certificate and private key pair does not exist in your keychain. Double check the certificate you had selected for the prov profile. Download it and place it again in your keychain. Then, reboot your computer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but from the question you can see that the provisioning profile references the 9V38BLC46F certificate, and it also states that this certificate is present along with its private key in the default keychain.

Comment: still, I would delete the certificates, download and them again. Maybe they are outdated?

Comment: They are not outdated.  They are valid, as the question states.  They've also been newly added.  Deleting and re-adding or rebooting makes no difference.

Comment: Can you check what certificate you chose for the prov profile (iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *) in the developer dite? Is the prov profile managed or generated by Xcode? You may manually create the development, production, and ad hoc profile with your valid certificate. Then, download it.